# Copying row and pasting in another sheet VBA

Tags: excel

I'm trying to copy a range of data from a CSV and paste it in the master tracking sheet. I have written a VBA but I keep getting a global error. the debugger keeps coming up with the `Range("a20:ab20")`. PasteSpecial being the issue. I'm not sure what is wrong with it. any help would be great. Also if you know how I could make this could general macros that when I open any CSV I can use this macro to sort and move my data, please could you advise me on how to do this. thanks, max

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lr As Long
Dim rowcount As Integer


Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\max.murrell\Documents                     \Coventry Gateway South\Tracking\Main\master tracking sheet.xlsm"

Workbooks("1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("20-22548").Select
 Range("a20:ab20").Copy
 Workbooks("master tracking sheet.xlsm").Activate
 Sheets("Recieved Results").Select


rowcount = Worksheets("Recieved Results").cells(Rows.Count,                      "a").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
ActiveSheet("rowcount").Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False




End Sub
```

Comment: You have syntax errors, e.g. `ActiveSheet("rowcount")` - suggest you read up on some basics. Also, please could you get in the habit of accepting answers to questions if they've helped you.

Comment: Hi SJR i am new to stackoverflow, how do you accept answers, i am more than willing to give feedback or credit where its due im just unsure in how i do so. thnaks max